# Normalize/Flatten a JS array using LoDash or similar?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to be able to normalize a javascript object or flatten it, I was hoping to be able to do something with lodash but I am at a loss. I tried writing my own converter but it seemed way over complicated and I though that lodash would be able to do something like this.

I am placing the Original Array I have, it has 3 items with sub arrays. (see below)

This is what I expect (creating my new object), so everything is flattened and added to the ‘name’ (see testProduct1 and testProduct2 below), if no colors, locations are available then the name is just the original name (see testProduct3 below).

```
{
   name: ‘testProduct1 RED NewYork’
},
{
   name: ‘testProduct1 RED London’
},
{
   name: ‘testProduct1 YELLOW NewYork’
},
{
   name: ‘testProduct1 YELLOW London’
},
{
   name: ‘testProduct2 WHITE NewYork’
},
{
   name: ‘testProduct2 WHITE London’
},
{
   name: ‘testProduct3’
}
```

Here is the example of the ORIGINAL array

```
{
    name: ‘testProduct1’,
    colors: [
       ‘RED’,
       ‘YELLOW’
    ],
    locations: [
       ‘New York’,
       ‘London’
    ]
},
{
    name: ‘testProduct2’,
    colors: [
       ‘WHITE’
    ],
    locations: [
       ‘New York’,
       ‘London’
    ]
},
{
    name: ‘testProduct3’,
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, isn't that *de*normalizing?

Comment: Curly quotes won't work very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want a `map`

```
list.map((element) => {
    return {
        name: [element.name].concat(element.colors, element.locations).join(' ')
    };
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't use fat arrow functions for your answer. Most browsers don't support them yet

Comment: I think it's fine to use fat arrow functions. They're supported natively in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, as well of course any transpiler. If the user is working in an environment where they're not, he can do a trivial rewrite. The more basic problem is that this answer doesn't work.

Comment: @acbabis By the way, the correct term is "arrow function'.

Comment: @torazaburo Actually, both are acceptable. From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): "An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has..."

Comment: @Acbabis Not really. The spec uses the term "arrow function". The "also known as" in the MDN page should be read as "also known colloquially as fat arrow function based on on earlier, now deprecated usage...".

Comment: @torazaburo Could you explain what part of it is deprecated? I thought "fat" just referred to the `=>` syntax which is still part of the spec.

Comment: Earlier in the spec process before it was nailed down, people used to use the term "fat arrow function". But the spec was written using the term "arrow function". The term 'fat arrow function" appears nowhere in the spec.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution in plain Javascript.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'testProduct1', colors: ['RED', 'YELLOW'], locations: ['New York', 'London'] }, { name: 'testProduct2', colors: ['WHITE'], locations: ['New York', 'London'] }, { name: 'testProduct3', }],
    flat = function (array) {
        var order = ['colors', 'locations'],
        r = [];
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            function getParts(parts) {
                if (parts.length >= order.length) {
                    parts.unshift(a.name);
                    r.push({ name: parts.filter(Boolean).join(' ') });
                    return;
                }
                (a[order[parts.length]] || ['']).forEach(function (b) {
                    getParts(parts.concat(b));
                });
            }
            getParts([]);
        });
        return r;
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(flat, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var resultArr = inArr.reduce((initArr, cur) =>
  {
    if (cur.colors && cur.locations)
    {
      cur.colors.forEach(col => 
      cur.locations.forEach(loc =>
        initArr.push({ name: cur.name + ' ' + col + ' ' + loc })));
    }  
    else
    {
      initArr.push({ name: cur.name });
    }

    return initArr;
  }, [] /* Passed as initArr */);
```

OR

Even more concise

```
var resultArr = inArr.reduce((initArr, cur) =>
  {
    for (let col of cur.colors || ['']) 
      for (let loc of cur.locations || [''])
        initArr.push({ name: (cur.name + ' ' + col + ' ' + loc).trim() });
    return initArr;
  }, [] /* Passed as initArr */);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to write a set of basic loops:

```
var result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let colors = arr[i].colors || [];
  for (let j = 0; j < colors.length; j++) {
    let locations = arr[i].locations || [];
    for (let k = 0; k < locations.length; k++) {
      result.push({name: arr[i].name + ' ' + colors[j] + ' ' + locations[k]]});
    ]
  }
}
```

If you really want to write this in functional style, then one idea is:

```
[].concat(...arr.map(
  elt => (elt.colors || []).map(
    color => (elt.locations || []).map(
      location => ({name: elt.name + ' ' + color + ' ' + location})))))
```

Comment: This won't work because the third item in the list doesn't have a `colors` property or `locations` property.